# Ruby session load issue in first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 sites A(other plateform) and B(on ruby), if i login from A and go to site B it should also shows 'welcome,user_name' but it is not loading the session in first time i have to reload the site B then it's shows the Username.

Site B is in ruby how can i load the session in first time open, have a look in below function.

```
  def create
    unless authenticated? && !current_user.empty?
      authenticate(auth_code: params[:code], encoded_id_token: params[:id_token])
      retrieve_and_persist_user_profile
      session[:initial_login] = true
    end
    render status: 200, json: @controller.to_json
  end
```

Comment: i confuse about the logic `!current_user.empty?`, could you explain it ? what happen if `current_user` is nil ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share sessions between different sites, unless they share the same domain.

If it's the case, you have to set you session cookie to be valid with subdomains:

```rb
# in config/environments/production.rb

config.session_store :cookie_store, 
                     key: '_my_app_session',
                     domain:  '.example.com'
```

(adapt the key and the domain to your needs)

When the domain starts with a dot, the session cookie will be sent along with calls to all the subdomains.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, will it help to load the session in first time?
because my issue is site isn't load the session in first time open, when i refresh the page or reopen in new tab then it load the session.

And domain is same.